# TinyXML Debian Installation

Tags: c++, tinyxml

Can someone give me some instructions on how to install TinyXML (or TinyXML++) to debian so I can use it from within my C++ app.

I've never installed a library before so I have no idea what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Refine your question if you got any clues from my answer, but still did not succeed. Good luck with development!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

on the command line:

sudo apt-get install libtinyxml-dev

should be all you need

alternatively you could use a gui packet manager (if your distro has one) and search for tinyxml

Comment: Can't find that package here, or anything related to tinyxml.

Comment: It is not in Debian stable (lenny) but in Debian testing (squeeze). In Ubuntu I don't know. http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=squeeze&searchon=names&keywords=tinyxml

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install it as a library, you can include the TinyXML code into your own project. That might prove easier to you.

In the TinyXML zip file you will find a Makefile and a file xmltest.cpp.
Unzip the directory, go into it with a shell and type "make".

Then just pretend xmltest.cpp is your program and go from there, modify it to suite your needs. Good luck!

This question is not so much about tinyxml as it is with toolchains and command line development on Unix like systems in general.

Comment: That seems like a pain, a library would be better tbh, or some way of using that inside my Makefile.

Comment: It builds a library, to install it just copy the .a file to /usr/local/lib and run ldconfig afterwards. As root. And add the include files /usr/local/include. But you need to point GCC to where the include files are then with a -I/usr/local/include  But read up on GNU make and GCC options, then these things will seem obvious.